# How to create my own html tag and validate it

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I want to create my own HTML tag because I am facing an issue in adding new div tag in TABS. I found the following method but it is not being validated showing the following error in w3 validate.

> Error: Element style not allowed as child of element body in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        tab-content-body{
            color: brown;
        }
    </style>
    <tab-content-body class="d">Hello</tab-content-body>

    <script>
        class tabcontentbody extends HTMLElement{
            constructor(){
                super();
            }
        }
        customElements.define('tab-content-body',tabcontentbody);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've worked with html validation for real, but in short you would need to;

1. Create your own xml schema to validate your html against.

This is basically a mapping that will tell a validator how valid input should look like (i.e. is `tab-content-body` a valid tag? Can it have any child tags? If so, how many? Etc). More about it on https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp

2. Change the DocType of your html to point to that validation schema.

Your would need to change from `<!DOCTYPE html>` to something that points to the validation file and the content type (In the old days `html 4.01` used `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`) More about this on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: If you don't mind will explain with example please